# Legacy Component and Firefox 11

Tags: asp.net, firefox, radeditor

An older component, specifically, RadEditor 5.6.5.0 is not rendering to Firefox 11.0.  It sees it as an unsupported browser and simply renders a textarea tag instead.  Is there a way to have the control treat it as a lower version of Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to update the ClientTarget

Page.ClientTarget = "Uplevel";

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2(v=vs.80).aspx